# Referencing handlebars variable in a loop

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am trying to build some dropdowns in Handlebars using a compiled template but it is not able to access my variable:

Handlebars:

```
{{#each options}}
<div class="control-group consumables-options">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">
            {{select 'task_services_options' ../bond_service_request_quantities quantity}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

JS:

```
var html = Handlebars.templates.service_request_consumable_options({
    bond_service_request_quantities: bond_quantities,
    options: opts
});
```

Where `bond_quantities` and `opts` are Arrays of Objects.

The select helper is from handlebars-form-helpers, but even in normal handlebars (`{{../bond_service_request_quantities.0.text}}`) I get an error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is that I was using two different versions of Handlebars. The project has v2.0.0 but npm installed 3.0.3 for the grunt task which compiles the templates.

Answer (score 0):

Your Handlebars template and javascript code look ok. From looking at the error message it looks like the variable "bond_quantities" is null.

This is an an example html file that I used to test your code. I've tried to simplify it as much as possible, adding the precompiled template directly to the page, hard coding the data.

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="handlebars.form-helpers.min.js"></script>

<script>
    (function() {
  var template = Handlebars.template, templates = Handlebars.templates = Handlebars.templates || {};
templates['service_request_consumable_options'] = template({"1":function(depth0,helpers,partials,data,blockParams,depths) {

    depths = [];
    depths[1] = data.root;

    return "<div class=\"control-group consumables-options\">\n    <div class=\"row-fluid\">\n        <div class=\"span2\">\n            "
    + this.escapeExpression((helpers.select || (depth0 && depth0.select) || helpers.helperMissing).call(depth0,"task_services_options",(depths[1] != null ? depths[1].bond_service_request_quantities : depths[1]),(depth0 != null ? depth0.quantity : depth0),{"name":"select","hash":{},"data":data}))
    + "\n        </div>\n    </div>\n</div>\n";
},"compiler":[6,">= 2.0.0-beta.1"],"main":function(depth0,helpers,partials,data,blockParams,depths) {
    var stack1;

  return ((stack1 = helpers.each.call(depth0,(depth0 != null ? depth0.options : depth0),{"name":"each","hash":{},"fn":this.program(1, data, 0, blockParams, depths),"inverse":this.noop,"data":data})) != null ? stack1 : "");
},"useData":true,"useDepths":true});
})();
</script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        HandlebarsFormHelpers.register(Handlebars);

        var bond_quantities = [ {
            value : 1,
            text : 'One'
        }, {
            value : 2,
            text : 'Two'
        } ];

        var opts = [ {
            quantity : 100
        }, {
            quantity : 200
        } ];

        var html = Handlebars.templates.service_request_consumable_options({
            bond_service_request_quantities: bond_quantities,
            options: opts
        });

        $('#target').html(html);
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="target"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No, if I output it outside the loop it works fine, it is there.

Comment: I use handlebars v2, does that matter?

Comment: It looks like in v2 the depths parameter is not being passed to the template. You can get the template to work by manually setting the parameter. I'll update the example.